# How do I change the object names within my javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I found some possible solutions on this site but none of them really helped me forward.

My array looks like this:

```
[
  {"customerName":"Atelier graphique","addressLine1":"54, rue Royale"},
  {"customerName":"Signal Gift Stores","addressLine1":"8489 Strong St."},
  etc, etc
```

I want to change the customerName to value and addressLine1 to data. I tried the following but I am doing something wrong here.

```
var myArray = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#text-id").on( 'click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'connect.php',

            success: function( data ) {
                console.log( data );
                myArray.push(data);

        }
    });
});


function DumpCustomers() {

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length; i++){
        myArray[i].addressLine1= "data";
        delete myArray[i].addressLine1;
        myArray[i].customerName= "value";
        delete myArray[i].customerName;
    }

    alert(myArray);

}
```

Comment: who is calling `DumpCustomers` - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't that far off, but ask yourself, what does this line do:

```
myArray[i].addressLine1= "data";
```

? Right — it sets the value of the `myArray[i].addressLine1` property to `"data"`. That's not what you want. :-) You want to add a new property called `data` to `myArray[i]` and give it the value currently in `myArray[i].addressLine1`. You do that by assigning to the new property name:

```
myArray[i].data = myArray[i].addressLine1;
```

E.g.:

```
function DumpCustomers() {
    var i;

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length; i++){
        myArray[i].data = myArray[i].addressLine1;  // Change here
        delete myArray[i].addressLine1;
        myArray[i].value = myArray[i].customerName; // And here
        delete myArray[i].customerName;
    }

    alert(myArray);

}
```

...and at some point, you'll need to have code calling `DumpCustomers`, or move the part changing the property names into your success handler instead.

Note that I added `var i` at the top. Your code was falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* without it.

That said, if these are the only two properties in the array entries, I'd probably go with `map` per [spender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender), or do something like your loop but completely replacing the entries rather than modifying them:

```
function DumpCustomers() {
    var i;

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length; i++){
        myArray[i] = {
            data: myArray[i].addressLine1,
            value: myArray[i].customerName
        };
    }

    alert(myArray);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to project your array values to the desired type:

```
var myTransformedArray = myOriginalArray.map(function(item){
    return {
       value : item.customerName,
       data : item.addressLine1
    };
});
```

If you need to support old browsers, you may need to add a polyfill to patch over the absence of a `map` function. The link above supplies this ECMA-262 5<sup>th</sup> Edition compliant implementation:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) {
  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {
    var T, A, k;
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }
    A = new Array(len);
    k = 0;
    while (k < len) {
      var kValue, mappedValue;
      if (k in O) {
        kValue = O[k];
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return A;
  };
}
```

Comment: This won't work in older browsers. Since OP is already using jQuery, consider [jQuery's `map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to support < IE 9: `$.map(myOriginalArray, function(item) { ....... })`

Comment: this ``map`` is not of jquery??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: No, the one being used by spender's answer is ES5's `Array#map`.

Comment: @Shai That won't work without jQuery. It's a huge patch to a very small problem. Better to use the Array.map polyfill in the link provided in my answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill

Comment: @spender In a project without jQuery I'd definitely recommend the polyfill. I'm glad you included it for people who read your answer in future. But the OP is already using jQuery – wouldn't including that polyfill be unnecessary code duplication?

Comment: @Shai : yes, I see your point. I tend to prefer the shim because it reduces dependencies which is always a good thing, especially if you ever reuse code.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: They're different functions. One, `Array#map`, is defined by ES5 and provided by all modern JavaScript engines. The other, `$.map`, is a jQuery function. They do similar things, but they're completely separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a **new** Array :)

*Like this:*

```
var myArray = [
  {"customerName":"Atelier graphique","addressLine1":"54, rue Royale"},
  {"customerName":"Signal Gift Stores","addressLine1":"8489 Strong St."}
],

newArray = [];
for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++)
{
    newArray.push({'value': myArray[i]['customerName'], 'data': myArray[i]['addressLine1']});
}

myArray = newArray;
```